# Scp from iPad (or alternative)

Tags: ipad, scp

I want to scp photos from my iPad to my server. I use MobileTerminal but ssh nor scp seem to be valid commands :S Guess it's not inatalled. Is there any way to install scp or a alternative that works like scp?

I don't have FTP on my server and I need to send large amounts of photos.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Since this question isn’t related to programming, it doesn’t belong on Stack Overflow. Consider asking it on http://apple.stackexchange.com instead.

Comment: Hmm okay.. Is those "rules" new? Didn't know.. Thanks for pointing it out though.

Comment: Not really, but apple.SE is relatively new. If you search for scp questions in Stack Overflow you’ll notice that questions related to the installation, configuration, and use of scp have mostly been migrated to superuser.com or serverfault.com.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SSH and SCP are included with the OpenSSH package (default Cydia repos). http://www.simonblog.com/2009/05/17/how-to-use-ssh-to-transfer-file-on-iphone/

Comment: Thank you sooo much! It works! .. Another question though. Can I disable so that no one can SSH into my iPad but I can scp out? (cause now my iPad is open for attacks)

Comment: Is there a non-jailbroken alternative? SSH works fine using the ServerAuditor or Prompt apps, but I can't find anything for SCP.